# Как включить подсказки в VS code для C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Я не знаю, они есть но не все, нету допустим "System", "Console". Может нужно расширение какое-то скачать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp ?

Comment: [Roslynator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=josefpihrt-vscode.roslynator)?

Answer (score 1):

Установите это расширение- [C# for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp)
А вообще заходите [сюда](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/VSCode) или в раздел "Расширения" в VS Code и ищете по ключевому слову "C#" или ".Net".

Comment: А что делать если не помогает. Я ввожу using Syst(типо не пишу дальше) а подсказка не вылазит