# Нету подсказок VS code C# для модуля System!

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, using

Если я допустим пишу "using Syst"(типо закончил писать и жду пока вылезет подсказка) и снизу не вылазиет подсказка System хоть и должна
Помогите прошу!!!
До этого учил Python и pygame
Visual Studio CODE "именно code"

Comment: Так Visual Studio или VS Code?

Comment: Visual Studio Code (именно code)

Comment: [Связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1487154/373567), возможный дубликат, то автору не помог ответ по ссылке. Прошу не закрывать этот вопрос.

Comment: Эта штука называется IntelliSense. Какие расширения у тебя установлены? Должно быть хотя бы **C#**. Какие расширения установлены можно посмотреть, нажав Ctrl+Shift+X или на соответствующую кнопку слева в столбике - 4 квадратика.

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено! Итак, я начал искать инфу про то, как включить подсказки VC code C# и наткнулся на какой-то форум, где сказали поробовать поставить более старую версию расширения C#.

Там где Uninstall нужно открыть всплывающий список и выбрать Install Another version:

[image]

И это помогло! Дело было в том, что расширение C# было последней версии и почему-то не показывало подсказок, а на версии 1.24.0 всё начало работать!

[image]

Эта или другая версия, в общем, советую не менее 1-6 мес. назад (хотя можете поробовать и другие).